# Equivalent conditions for an ideal to be prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-verification, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. An ideal $I$ is called *prime* if whenever $ab\in I$ then $a\in I$ or $b\in I$. I want to show that $I$ is prime if whenever $JK\subseteq I$, then $J\subseteq I$ or $K\subseteq I$. I want to show a third equivalent condition, so that I have:

1. $I$ is prime.
2. Whenever $XY\subseteq I$, then $X\subseteq I$ or $Y\subseteq I$ for subsets $X,Y\subseteq R$, $XY$ is the complex product $\{xy\mid x\in X,y\in Y\}$.
3. Whenever $JK\subseteq I$, then $J\subseteq I$ or $K\subseteq I$ for ideals $J,K\subseteq R$, $JK$ is the ideal product.

My attempt is as follows:

$(1)\implies (2)$: Suppose $X,Y\not\subseteq I$ but $XY\subseteq I$. Let $a\in X-I$, $b\in Y-I$. Then $a,b\notin I$ but $ab\in XY\subseteq I$.

$(2)\implies(3)$: Let $JK\subseteq I$. Choose generating sets $(X)=J$, $(Y)=K$. Then $(XY)=(X)(Y)=JK\subseteq I$, so $XY\subseteq I$, so $X\subseteq I$ or $Y\subseteq I$, so $J\subseteq I$ or $K\subseteq I$.

$(3)\implies(1)$: Suppose $I$ is not prime. Let $a,b\notin I$ such that $ab\in I$. Now take $J=(a)$, $K=(b)$. Then 3. is not satisfied.

> Is this proof correct?

Comment: That looks correct, although in (2) -> (3), there is no need to consider generating sets. Just let $X=J$ and $Y=K$.

Comment: Yes, this would be one possible choice. I just wanted to make clear where I am using (2). Would you mind making your comment an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Though in (2) => (3), you can choose $X = J, Y = K$, instead of choosing them as generating sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks fine, clear and well-written. My only suggestion is that you could simplify $(2)\implies(3)$ by just letting $X=J$ and $Y=K$ and then applying $(2)$. If you want to be clear about where you are using $(2)$, just say so explicitly in the proof. It's conceptually simpler than finding generating sets.